# Having issue running my simulatiion on OMNeT++ given a run time error

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I use instant Veins for this work. i have build `*.net.xml`, `*.rou.xml` and `*.sumocfg` and also prep my Launchd but when i want to run my simulation am having error of not being able to connect to TraCIserver. error is:

> A runtime error occurred. Connection to TraCI server lost. Check your
> serverlogs. Error message: 104: connectionreset by peer --in
> Module(veins::TraCIScenarioMahagerLaunchd) helloNetwork.manager(id=6),
> at t=0s, event#1 launch a debuger with the following commands? nemiver
> --attach = 38598

i was just trying to check if i didn't edit my `omnetpp.ini` but i couldn't see anything wrong

Comment: Have you started the ```veins_launchd```?

Comment: yes i actually started it on the instant veins but not from the terminal

Comment: What is written in the log output of the ```veins_launchd```?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the instantVEINS has access to the internet. It might work once the internet connection is established.